# Zepto - Can't cancel link tap on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, touch, zepto

I think I must be missing something obvious, but I can't use preventDefault to cancel navigating to a link's href when the link is tapped on an iPad (it works ok on my Android phone though).

I have a very simple test page, which has this on:

```
<a id="mn" href="http://www.google.com">Some link</a>
<script>
    document.write('<script src=js/' +
            ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto.min' : 'jquery-1.6.2.min') +
            '.js><\/script>');

    if ('__proto__' in {}) {
        document.write('<script src=js/touch.js><\/script>');
    }

    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $('#mn').tap(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });
            }
    );
</script>
```

The tap event is called, if I stick an alert in there it fires ok, but the action of clicking the link is never cancelled. What am I missing?!

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: You need to include the touch.js module for tap events: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/touch.js

Comment: Sorry, yes you are, I missed the second include. I am not sure you need the `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagation()` methods - https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/examples/touch_events.html

Comment: I 'think' I do (preventDefault at least), as the item is an anchor tag (in those examples none of the things being clicked are links).

Comment: Yep, you are correct, sorry for adding to the confusion. Maybe post a fiddle and I will try and help.